# Find surface $S$ using parametrization of a surface

Tags: calculus

Consider the parametrization of a surface:
$$r = \langle u \text{ cos}(v), u^2 \text{ cos}(2v), u \text{ sin}(v) \rangle$$
The question asks to find surface $S$. I'm new learning calculus $3$ and having trouble to approach this question.

Any hint or suggestion would be really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Note

$$y=u^2\cos 2 v = u^2(\cos^2v-\sin^2v)=x^2-z^2$$